How to get NDC for a UPC
We are trying to identify, pharma that is sold in California based on UPC. Is there a way to find the NDC for a given UPC using the openfda API. We have use the API, downloaded the package and product files, but there is no UPC in any of the files. What is the best way to go about this search.
